# Button, updating a list item at the Display Page

Tags: jsom, updatelistitems, update, itemupdated

I am trying to create a button on the Display Page where it will update a value (Open, Close, Cancel), either redirecting them back to the Display Page or just taking them back to the List Page.

They want the button so I have to create a button ***(sigh)***.
When I click the button, when it gets to the clientContext line (set as variable oList), it states that 404 error, file not found.  Its based on the ***siteURL*** (which I think is causing the problem).
  Here is the code (I got this from MSDN. See link at end of post):

```
<input type="button" value="Close Testing" onclick="updateListItem();" />
<script>
var siteUrl ="Lists/ListWithAlotOfCrap";
var urlParam=GetUrlKeyValue("ID");
function updateListItem() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("RiskMgmt");
    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(urlParam);
    oListItem.set_item("State", "Close");
    oListItem.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert("Item updated!");
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert("Request failed. " + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

Any Suggestions?
Here's the source link:
[How to update a list Item value on a button click using a javascript or Jquery SharePoint Desiginer 2010](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/50d12ef5-ee4f-407e-82e9-434a26dc57b5/how-to-update-a-list-item-value-on-a-button-click-using-a-javascript-or-jquery-sharepoint-desiginer?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `updateListItem()` function:

Use `var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();`

instead of `var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);`.

Also, make sure that you are passing display name(Not the name in URL) of list in following line:

```
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("RiskMgmt");
```

Comment: Thanks @ganesh-sanap.  As far as the var oList variable, isn't it the name of the List?  And use the List name?  Also, the clientContext is showing as [object object], not sure if anything is being passed at the clientContext.

Comment: Disregard @ganesh-sanap.  It worked!  I had to change the List Name from Production to Dev...worked beautifully!  I'm marking this as an answer!  many thanks!